# Retrieving parse.com data in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I've been able to save successfully to Parse via Swift, but am having trouble retrieving data (and all of the tutorials on retrieving seem to be for Obj-C).

Here's my code (with Id's redacted).

```
Parse.setApplicationId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", clientKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")


    var query = PFQuery(className: "EventObject")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId: String!) {
        (event: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println(event)

        } else {

        println(error)

        }

    }
```

I have 4 records in this class right now, but if I want to pull the data for all of them, how do I get the Object using the ID if I'm not sure what the IDs are? I'm assuming I can access them sequentially as an array, but I'm not quite clear how to do that, and am confused, as the only command I know to retrieve appears to require knowing the ID.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official [parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS) explains how to make queries - there is sample code in swift.

In your case you have to use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"EventObject")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    for object in objects {
        // Do something
    }
  } else {
      println(error)
  }
}
```

which, if successful, provides to the closure an array of objects matching the query - since there's no filter set in the query, it just returns all records.

Comment: I got this error message, /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Controllers/Profile/TableViewController.swift:40:15: Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Comment: But how we can retrieve all objects. I mean all rows from the table?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.1 Update

```
func fetchFromParse() {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Your_Class_Name")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                // Do something
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for fetch objects in **Swift3.0**.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Your_Class_Name")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error == nil {

        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Retrive Data from parse: **swift 3**

```
 let adventureObject = PFQuery(className: "ClassName")
    adventureObject.addAscendingOrder("objectId")
    var objectID: String = String()
    adventureObject.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (Success, error) in
    })
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.